# Swift and Firebase Project Runs on simulator Error on an actual Device

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing an iOS App using Firebase SDK, The app runs perfectly on the simulator, but when I try to run it on an actual device I'm getting an error like this[image]

Also when I'm trying to archive it. I forgot to tell that I used cocoapods to install Firebase SDK. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to remove and re-add Firebase using the podfile?

Comment: Yes, I also tried to remove firebase and re-install it.

Comment: I did it a million times :)

Answer (score 2):

I had this error because the xcode version. 
I have created the project using the xcode beta version, then i updated it and got this error.

hours later, when I gave up trying to resolve this error, when trying to install another pod, this error occurred:

> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:118:in `git_version': Failed to extract git version from`git --version`("xcrun: error: active developer path (\"/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer\") does not exist\nUse`sudo xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app`to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools, or use`xcode-select --install`to install the standalone command line developer tools.\nSee`man xcode-select` for more details.\n") (RuntimeError) ...

when trying to run the

> pod-install command

Then I ran the sudo

> xcode-select command --switch path / to / Xcode.app

which was prompted for the error, and the Firebase-related error was miraculously fixed. Hope it could helps someone.